# How to modify this predicate so it handles multiple keywords efficiently

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I have this predicate:

```
NSPredicate * thePredicateKeyword = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any keywords.thekeyword beginswith [cd] %@", searchTerm];
```

Basically each business have many to many relationship with keywords.

But suppose I do not have one searchTerm. Say I have an array.

How would I do so?

I suppose I can just make predicate for each and combine them with or predicate, etc.

However, is there a way to more efficiently do this using `in` keywords or stuff like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a function that returns something like this:

```
-(NSPredicate *)createCompoundPredicateForSearchTerms:(NSArray *)searchTerms
{
  NSMutableArray *subPredicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  NSEnumerator *searchTermEnum = [searchTerms objectEnumerator];
  NSString *searchTerm;
  while (searchTerm = [searchTermEnum nextObject]) {
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"keywords.thekeyword beginswith [cd] %@", searchTerm];
    [subPredicates addObject:predicate];
  }

  return [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
}
```

Comment: I already know how to do it this way. I wonder if we can use 'in' to do it in a more efficient way.

Comment: What about something like this NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchTerm]; Alternatively, would predicateWithBlock give you the control you are looking for to improve the efficiency?

Comment: I want to use beginswith not contains. If there is no better answer, your answer will confirm that this is indeed the way and I'll select that.

Comment: Sorry, thats all I have tonight.

Comment: yap that seems to be the way to go.

Comment: VERY GOOD! I would use for in though.

Comment: TY! I am on a while kick (when I can get my hands on NSEnumerators). Do you know of a performance or other issue that might affect my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I actually use. However, the anwer I chose is what inspire it.

```
NSArray * keywords = [searchTerm componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSMutableArray * keywordPredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString * aKeyword in keywords) {
    NSPredicate * thePredicateKeyword = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any keywords.thekeyword beginswith [cd] %@", aKeyword];
    [keywordPredicates addObject:thePredicateKeyword];
}

NSPredicate * thePredicateKeyword = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:keywordPredicates];

return thePredicateKeyword;
```